# Xamarin ContentView renderer hides Content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have such class:

```
          public class MetroButton: ContentView
        {

            public MetroButton ()
            {
                //create and filling mainGrid
                this.Content = mainGrid;
            }
        }
```

This works ok. But when i renderer my ContentView (MetroButton) - content not displayed (Content disappears , there remains only the main control).

My Render:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MetroButton), typeof(RendererToClickView))]
```

...

```
public class RendererToClickView:ViewRenderer
{
    public RendererToClickView ()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try inheriting the RendererToClickView from a ContentViewRenderer

Comment: ContentViewRenderer - does not exist,  or I do not know where to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `ContentViewRenderer`. Try to use `FrameRenderer` and just disable border drawing. That works good (tried it by myself).

```net
    public class MyFrame : Frame
    {
        public MyFrame()
        {
            Content = new Label() {
                Text = "Test"
            };
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
            OutlineColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyFrame), typeof (MyFrameRenderer))]
namespace YourAssembly.Droid
{
    public class MyFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public MyFrameRenderer()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i have exeption in the MainActivity.cs on the line "base.OnCreate (bundle);"  Maybe it's because I have not turned off  border drawing. Because I do not know exactly where it is necessary to disable =)

Comment: Edited my answer with an example

Comment: Yes , it was my fault . I have not changed "ContentView" to "Frame". Now I put the property "Padding" = 0  and it works perfectly. Thank you very much , man!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a `FrameRenderer` for this.
The renderer of a `ContentView` is a `ViewRenderer`, as can be seen in the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/):

You can do something like this:

```net
[Assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ImageGallery), typeof (ImageGalleryRenderer))]
Namespace MRV.AppClient.Mobile.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
     Class ImageGalleryRenderer: ViewRenderer
     {
         Protected override void JavaFinalize ()
         {
             ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache ();
             Base.JavaFinalize ();
         }
     }
}
```